# Navigation Bar color is not saving

Tags: ios, swift

I have view controllers with two different navigation bars. Every navigation bar has different color.

[VC1 and VC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll3zA.jpg)

If I move from VC1 to VC2 I will see different colors but if move back I will see in VC1 navigation bar's color from VC2.

[View Controller 1 Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRGW4.png)

So navigation bar color from VC1 is not saving properly

VC1:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController_1: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 56.0/255.0, green: 208.0/255.0, blue: 125.0/255.0, alpha: 1.00)

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }
```

VC2:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController_2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 105.0/255.0, green: 28.0/255.0, blue: 56.0/255.0, alpha: 1.00)

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }
```

How to make fixed navigation bar color in VC1? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the color of the navigation bar in the viewDidLoad, do it in viewWillAppear:

VC1

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 56.0/255.0, green: 208.0/255.0, blue: 125.0/255.0, alpha: 1.00)
    }
```

VC2

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 105.0/255.0, green: 28.0/255.0, blue: 56.0/255.0, alpha: 1.00)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you present from VC1 to VC2, they have different navigation controller. So, there should not be any problem about navigation bars color. Because they use different navigations. However If you push from VC1 to VC2 and when you move back from VC2 to VC1, you should set VC1's navigation bar color in `viewWillAppear` method. Because when you move back to VC1, it continuous to run with `viewWillAppear`, not with `viewDidLoad` due to VC1 already created in memory.